# Whether the live mqtt messages will be stored in MongoDB within Ditto solution? How can I check if these messages stored?

Tags: iot, eclipse-ditto, eclipse-iot, eclipse-digital-twin

From Ditto architecture, MongoDB should store all MQTT messages. Not sure the live messages? When I go into MongoDB, query collection, can't find anything although I find "things" db has certain size. Is there anyway to check if mqtt messages have been stored in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Live messages are not stored in MongoDB as described in the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/protocol-twinlive.html#live).
Only [twin commands](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/protocol-twinlive.html#twin) affect the persisted state of a digital twin / thing in the database.

If you however mean that the payload of your MQTT message is a twin command, that one should change the persisted state of a twin.

If you need to check in the database, check the `things_journal` prefixed MongoDB collections if the event which resulted from a twin command was persisted (see also the [architectural style](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-signals.html#architectural-style) docs).